# concatenating 2 strings issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have another issue that I do not know what has caused it. I am new to Oracle and I am tumbling on concatenating 2 strings. I have a function that is going to take a DateStart, DateStop and other variables then turn them into a SQL stmt. The function was compiling fine but has the following error when executed:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512 at line ...

At first I thought that one of the strings might be missing a quote, but both of the strings are fine as the function did not generate error when I printed the single one out. It had issue only when both of them are combined! 
It may be something obvious that I have overlooked, I have even tried concat instead of the operator "||", but I was not able to pin point the cause of the issue. If someone has come across this issue before, I would appreciate it if you could give me a hint of what I was doing incorrectly.

This is the function that caused me issue, I have trimmed out all other irrelevant codes so that we could zero in the problem. The function compiled correctly but had issue when executed.

Thanks!

```
create or replace
FUNCTION ABC(
    DateStart IN VARCHAR2 ,
    DateStop  IN VARCHAR2 ,
    ZipCode   IN VARCHAR2 ,
    PracticeID IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_code  NUMBER;
  v_errm  VARCHAR2(64);
  sqlstmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  sqlstmt2 VARCHAR2(500);
  sConditionClause VARCHAR2(500);
  s_Quote VARCHAR(1) := chr(39);
BEGIN
  sqlstmt2 :='SELECT TO_CHAR("Date", ''yyyy-mm-dd'') AS "Date" ,            
               substr(trim("Postal"),1,5) AS "ZipCode" ,                         
               count ("Patient") AS "Total" ';
  sConditionClause := ' FROM "ABC_TABLE"  WHERE "Date">=To_Date('
                      ||s_Quote || trim(DateStart) ||s_Quote
                      ||','
                      ||s_Quote||'mm/dd/yyyy'||s_Quote||')AND "Date"<=To_Date('
                      ||s_Quote || trim(DateStop) ||s_Quote
                      ||','||s_Quote||'mm/dd/yyyy'||s_Quote||') ';  
  sqlstmt := trim(sqlstmt2)||trim(sConditionClause);

  RETURN sqlstmt;
END;
```

Comment: I just tried creating and running this function with some sensible values for the parameters and it worked fine. Could you let us know what parameters you are using ?

Comment: (1) tell us which line the error is reported on; (2) tell us the length of the parameters `DateStart` and `DateStop`; (3) check how many spaces are being added to `sqlstmt2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found out: The function above may not have issue and the concatenation was fine. The issue was from the unit test Run PL/SQL provided by SQL Developer. It defaulted the return value string with a length of 200 char?!. I was not familiar enough with SQL Developer to discover it and blamed on my own function. As soon as I changed the length of the return string to varchar2(5000) everything run like a charm

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables (`sqlstmt2`, `sConditionClause`, or `sqlstmt`) is too small for the string you're trying to assign to it. If you had included the line number that the error is occurring on, we'd know which one.

Incidentally, you can use two single quotes together to add a single quite to a string, rather than having to use `s_Quote` as you are.

You could avoid this issue altogether by skipping the local variables:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION ABC(
    DateStart IN VARCHAR2,
    DateStop  IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN      
  RETURN 'SELECT TO_CHAR("Date", ''yyyy-mm-dd'') AS "Date" ,            
           substr(trim("Postal"),1,5) AS "ZipCode" ,                         
           count ("Patient") AS "Total" 
           FROM "ABC_TABLE"  WHERE "Date">=To_Date(''' 
           || trim(DateStart) 
           ||''',''mm/dd/yyyy'') AND "Date"<=To_Date('''
           || trim(DateStop) 
           ||''',''mm/dd/yyyy'')';
END ABC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I did not have issue if I would not concatenate the 2 strings. As mentioned about, both strings were printing fine if printed alone. So, I doubt that the variables do not have enough space. Your response was my original code but I need other variables as well because the output is dependent of other variables. The whole function has a lot more stuff in it but I have traced the issue down to the code above. In other word, I need to concatenate. I am just not sure what was the issue with the concatenation.

Comment: Thank you, Stevo and Jeffrey for looking into it. This is what I found out: The function above may not have issue and the concatenation was fine. The issue was from the unit test Run PL/SQL provided by SQL Developer. It defaulted the return value string with a length of 200 char?!. I was not familiar enough with SQL Developer to discover it and blamed on my own function. As soon as I changed the length of the return string to varchar2(5000) everything run like a charm... Thank you everyone for looking into it. I knew it was an overlook of my part but I did not know where to look....